# HTML5 Draggable attribute: prevent the helper to show up

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, draggable

I've made this little script to create a draggable DIV using the `dragabble` property in HTML5, everything works fine except that helper which shows up at the end of the drag. Is there a way to prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ubugnu/66AVB/

```
<div id="toBeDragged" style="position: absolute;" draggable="true">
  This text <strong>may</strong> be dragged.
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('toBeDragged').addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
    X = event.offsetX;
    Y = event.offsetY;
});
document.getElementById('toBeDragged').addEventListener('drag', function(event) {
    this.style.left = event.pageX - X + 'px';
    this.style.top = event.pageY - Y + 'px';
});
</script>
```

Edit:
It seems that it does not work on Firefox! Anyone has an idea on why it doesn't work?

Comment: what are you trying to do. By default there is image of element that follows mouse when it's being dragged. Which can be changed. But you are adding the copy of image to mimic the same behavior and then wanting to remove the real one. Why.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not follow you, what I want is this "ghost" image that follows mouse to not reappear at the end of the drag

Comment: I think the word "helper" is really not appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#dragstart) docs on drag start.

You need to set some drag data so Firefox will know how to display the drag information.  It's non-standard that it works in other browsers.

I updated your fiddle by adding

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'This text <strong>may</strong> be dragged');
```

to your dragStart event.

See if that's the behavior you want: http://jsfiddle.net/66AVB/1/

Comment: Sorry, the "ghost" copy of the dragged element still appear

Comment: This is the fix to make it work on firefox (and be standards compliant with the others).  I'm not sure what you mean by the ghost copy - by setting the data the way I did, it deliberately shows the contents of that div when you're dragging.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Still not working on FF23
The problem is not during the drag, but when the drag ends, a "ghost copy" of the element returns to the initial place :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you could use jquery, why not just use jquery ui while at it.

http://jsfiddle.net/66AVB/2/

all code that you need is this:

`$('#toBeDragged').draggable();`

Comment: Alas, I need it in pure JS